# How to add datasetKeyProvider to react chartjs

Tags: reactjs, charts, react-chartjs

I have Line chart on my react project. I want to translate labels and chart breaks if component re renders after I switch language. Error is "Cannot read property 'getPixelForValue' of undefined" so if I hard code labels errors is gone. I found that I should use datasetKeyProvider if I want unique string value. But I have problem in implementing that.

I tried to set it like this:

```
class LineChart extends Component {
datasetKeyProvider() {
        return Math.random();
    }

render() {
  return (
    <>
     <Line 
     data={this.state.chartData}
     datasetKeyProvider={this.datasetKeyProvider}
     options={{
       legend: {
         display: true,
         position: "bottom"
       },
       maintainAspectRatio: false,
       scales: {
         xAxes: [
          {
            type: "time",
            time: {
            unit: "year"
                   }
               }
            ]
       />
    </>
  )
}
}
```